# Efficient way to filter out elements from std::vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, boost, stl

I have ended up to following code in order to filter out some bad elements from an `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef struct mystruct {
    int id;
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{        
    std::vector<mystruct> all_items = {{151, "test1"}, {154, "test4"}, {152, "test2"}, {151, "test1"}, {151, "test1"}, {153, "test3"}};
    std::vector<int> bad_ids = {151, 152};
    std::vector<mystruct> filter_items;

    for (const auto& item : all_items) {
        if ( std::find(bad_ids.begin(), bad_ids.end(), item.id) != bad_ids.end() ) {
            std::cout << "id: " << item.id << " is bad" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "id: " << item.id << " is good item" << std::endl;
            filter_items.emplace_back(item);
        }
    }

    for (auto f : filter_items) {
        std::cout << "Good item: " << f.id << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is there any more efficient way? Can the `std::remove_copy_if` or Boost be used here and how?

Comment: If you have working code to improve better ask at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks! Can I easily transfer it to SE Code Review or should I copy/paste it?

Comment: Yes, just copy your whole question markup. Put it as question there, and remove this one.

Comment: How many elements in `bad_ids` do you actually have  in your application? If more than a few then you might benefit from using a set.

Comment: @RustyX: I expect to be a few elements in `bad_ids` and non-unique.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can use [std::remove_copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy), e.g.

```
std::remove_copy_if(
  all_items.begin(), 
  all_items.end(), 
  std::back_inserter(filter_items),
  [&bad_ids](const mystruct& item) { return std::find(bad_ids.begin(), bad_ids.end(), item.id) != bad_ids.end(); });
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/LKRS73001)

Or you can use [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) the *bad* elements on the vector directly, e.g.

```
all_items.erase(
  std::remove_if(
    all_items.begin(), 
    all_items.end(), 
    [&bad_ids](const mystruct& item) { return std::find(bad_ids.begin(), bad_ids.end(), item.id) != bad_ids.end(); }), 
  all_items.end());
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/IXHFA72957)

Answer (score 5):

expanding on @songyuanyao's correct answer, it never hurts to keep a little library of container helpers to make code more expressive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct mystruct {
    int id;
    std::string name;
};

template<class T, class A, class Pred>
std::vector<T, A> copy_unless(std::vector<T, A> container, Pred&& pred)
{
    container.erase(std::remove_if(container.begin(), container.end(), 
                                   std::forward<Pred>(pred)), 
                    container.end());
    return container;
}

template<class Container, class Pred>
bool any_match(Container&& container, Pred&& pred)
{
    return std::find_if(container.begin(), container.end(), pred) != container.end();
}

int main()
{        
    std::vector<mystruct> all_items = {{151, "test1"}, {154, "test4"}, {152, "test2"}, {151, "test1"}, {151, "test1"}, {153, "test3"}};
    std::vector<int> bad_ids = {151, 152};

    auto is_bad = [&bad_ids](mystruct const& item)
    {
        auto match_id = [&item](int id){ return item.id == id; };
        return any_match(bad_ids, match_id);
    };

    auto filter_items = copy_unless(all_items, is_bad);

    for (auto&& f : filter_items) {
        std::cout << "Good item: " << f.id << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm sure I remember a library like this in boost, but for the life of me I can't remember which one it is.

Comment: Did you think of Boost Range? [Perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46268897/85371)

Comment: @sehe I think that's the one. It's interesting to me that i've never used it. I'm not comfortable with the algorithm interface - the idea of specifying the return type as a template argument seems a little archaic. I'm sure we as a community could do better.

Comment: `copy_range` is the odd one out though. By the way, Boost _is_ we as a community. Contribute :)

Comment: @sehe working on a solution at the moment. I am certain we can make algorithms that are expressive, efficient and 100% safe. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest Boost Range:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac787fd799c44c69)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    myvec all_items = { { 151, "test1" }, { 154, "test4" }, { 152, "test2" },
                        { 151, "test1" }, { 151, "test1" }, { 153, "test3" } };

    auto is_good = [bad_ids = std::set<int> { 151, 152 }](mystruct v) {
        return bad_ids.end() == bad_ids.find(v.id); 
    };

    // just filter on the fly:
    for (auto& f : all_items | filtered(is_good)) {
        std::cout << "Good item: " << f.id << std::endl;
    }

    // actually copy:
    auto filter_items = boost::copy_range<myvec>(all_items | filtered(is_good));
}
```

Prints

```
Good item: 154
Good item: 153
```

### Improving...

You could improve style by factoring things out a little:

Assuming you have a utility like `contains`:

```
template <typename... Arg, typename V> bool contains(std::set<Arg...> const &set, V const &v) {
    return set.end() != set.find(v);
}

template <typename... Arg, typename V> bool contains(std::vector<Arg...> const &vec, V const &v) {
    return vec.end() != std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), v);
}
```

Then it becomes more readable:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49d1f6ee096791ae)</kbd>**

```
auto is_good = [&bad_ids](auto& v) { return !contains(bad_ids, v.id); };

for (auto& f : all_items | filtered(is_good)) {
    std::cout << "Good item: " << f.id << std::endl;
}
```

Now, I feel like the whole `bad_ids` list could probably also be dynamic. But if it weren't, you could be more "in-place" using Phoenix:

### Peak Hipster:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b70f24e5ef5bddac)</kbd>**

```
for (auto& f : all_items | filtered(!contains_(std::set<int> { 151, 152 }, arg1->*&mystruct::id))) {
    std::cout << "Good item: " << f.id << std::endl;
}
```

I know. That's pushing it for no good reason, but hey. Just showing :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `partition` algorithm? It will re-arrange `all_items` such that good items are placed first and bad afterwards.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition

Comment: std::remove_if also effectively does the same thing

_Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to be removed appear in the beginning of the range_